# Как вывести переменную на обе команды?

Tags: python, discord.py

У меня есть переменные member и time, мне нужно, чтоб при окончании голосования выдавалась роль на определенное время. Сама проблема в том, что в конце не выдается роль по завершению голосования

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def startvote(ctx, member = discord.Member = None): 
    if member == None:
        return

    channel = ctx.channel
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f'@everyone ЩАС КТО-ТО  УЛЕТИТ В НОКАУТ.', description=f"Улетает {member.mention}",
                                  colour=discord.Color.blue())
    message = await ctx.send(embed=emb)
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await message.add_reaction('❌')
    global message_id 
    message_id = message.id 




@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def endvote(ctx):

    channel = ctx.channel
    message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id) 
    resactions = [reaction for reaction in message.reactions if reaction.emoji in ['✅', '❌']]
    result = ''
    for reaction in resactions:
        result += reaction.emoji + ": " + str(reaction.count - 1)
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f'Короче', description='Итог голосования: ' + str(result),
                                  colour=discord.Color.orange())
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)




    if int(result[3]) > int(result[7]):
        await member.add_roles(1016473374731534386)
        await asyncio.sleep(time)
        await member.remove_roles(1016473374731534386)
    else:
        await ctx.send("каким образом он не улетел?")
```

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий вариант выглядеть как-то так (Ошибки и алгоритм я описал в комментариях):

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!!", intents=intents)


role_id = 123  # id роли, которую нужно выдать
vote_message_id: int = 0
vote_member_id: int = 0


async def temp_role(member: discord.Member, role: discord.Role, time: int) -> None:
    await member.add_roles(role)  # Выдаем роль
    await asyncio.sleep(time)  # Асинхронно ждём
    await member.remove_roles(role)  # Забираем роль


@bot.command(name='startvote')
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def start_vote(ctx: commands.Context, member: discord.Member = None) -> None:  # Аннотация типов указывается так "переменная: тип = None", а не "переменная = тип = None"
    global vote_message_id, vote_member_id

    if member is None:
        await ctx.channel.send("Укажите пользователя")
        return

    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'ЩАС КТО-ТО  УЛЕТИТ В НОКАУТ.', description=f"Улетает {member.mention}", colour=discord.Color.blue())
    message = await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)

    asyncio.create_task(message.add_reaction('✅'))
    asyncio.create_task(message.add_reaction('❌'))

    vote_message_id = message.id  # сохраняем пользователя и сообщение в глобальную переменную
    vote_member_id = member.id


@bot.command(name='endvote')
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def end_vote(ctx: commands.Context) -> None:
    global vote_message_id, vote_member_id

    if not vote_message_id or not vote_member_id:
        await ctx.channel.send("Голосование ещё не начиналось")
        return

    member = await ctx.guild.fetch_member(vote_member_id)  # Получаем объект пользователя
    message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(vote_message_id)  # Получаем объект сообщения
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(role_id)

    reactions = [reaction for reaction in message.reactions if reaction.emoji in ['✅', '❌']]  # Считаем голоса
    reactions_yes = reactions[0].count
    reactions_no = reactions[1].count

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Результаты", description=f"{reactions_yes}:{reactions_no}", colour=discord.Color.orange())
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)

    if reactions_yes > reactions_no:
        asyncio.create_task(temp_role(member, role, 10))  # Выдаём роль; 10 (в секундах) - на сколько нужно выдать роль

    vote_message_id = 0  # Обнуляем пользователя и сообщение
    vote_member_id = 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run("token")
```